# Merging file with different headers without changing headers

Tags: excel, automation, powerquery

I have multiple files with student data, Column A has the test name (Unit-1, Sem-1, Unit-2, Sem-2) and row 1 is a merged cell header that gives the student name, row 2 gives the all subject name of students enrolled (different column each), and finally the score for each subject in each test and the totals of all the test in the bottom.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Student | JOHN | ALEX |  |  |  |  |
| Subjects | ENG | MAT | SCI | ENG | MAT | SCI |
| Unit-I | 73 | 74 | 55 | 52 | 71 | 62 |
| Sem-I | 68 | 72 | 99 | 82 | 64 | 81 |
| Unit-II | 52 | 52 | 53 | 86 | 52 | 63 |
| Sem-II | 75 | 58 | 77 | 70 | 90 | 97 |
| Total | 268 | 256 | 284 | 290 | 277 | 303 |

as the headers (student names) are different in each excel file, I'm unable to combine them using the query editor, and also I want to unpivot the data to have the names, subjects, and total in a horizontal arrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source,1),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Removed Top Rows",{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"}),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Other Columns", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Studet", each Source{0}[Column2]),

#"Removed Other Columns2" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Removed Top Rows",{"Column1", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7"}),
#"Promoted Headers2" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Other Columns2", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Studet", each Source{0}[Column3]),

Combined = Table.Combine({#"Added Custom",#"Added Custom2"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Combined, {"Subjects", "Studet"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Subjects] <> "Total"))
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

[image]

You can then pivot or group as needed

Comment: Thanks you so much for taking out your time to help with this query.

The question was edit by someone which might have caused the confusion, there is a small correction, iro this question, the table had 6 columns, eng, mat & sci for student 1 'john' and again same subjects for student 2 'alex'. 

below is how the final result is expected.

|Student |Sub  |Total|
|John     |ENG  |##|
|John     |MAT  |##|
|John     |SCI    |##|
|Alex      |ENG  |##|
|Alex      |MAT  |##|
|Alex      |SCI    |##|

Comment: changed answer above, my bad edit

Comment: thank you again for taking out your time, can't thank you enough. but I have multiple excel files like this which itself have multiple sheets like this. I tried and I'm able to format the single tab, (just like you), but when you merge multiple excel/sheets, you will get more than one column that will have a subject in it. and that is where I'm facing the challenge.

Comment: you just need to make this a function to apply against each of the files you read in.  If it works for one, it will work sequentially on all of them